# MySQL TIMESTAMP isn't behaving as advertised

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL 5.5.34. The [5.5 Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html) says I can create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts1 TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0,
  ts2 TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

From the documentation:

> For t1, ts1 is NOT NULL and assigning it a value of NULL sets it to the current timestamp.

The documentation also says I can only assign `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as the default to a single `TIMESTAMP` field only. No multiple fields auto updating.

So, I tried this exact trick:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  blah blah blah,
  `record_created` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0,
  `last_updated` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

When I execute the `CREATE` command, I get this back:

```
ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'record_created'
```

and the table doesn't actually get created.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mysql server's global configuration don't allow you to insert ZEROS into table column. 
The global configuration parameter ***SQL_mode*** is responsible for this behavior. You can find it in your my.ini file if configured or you can also query mysql server to display its value,

```
select @@SQL_mode;
```

It should return you 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES,**NO_ZERO_IN_DATE**', which needs to be reset by sql command `set global SQL_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';` or as per your requirement.

Comment: That was the clue I needed. MAMP doesn't actually set an SQL_mode. I had to figure out where MAMP wanted its my.cnf file to configure the global SQL_mode. Then, I enjoyed the red herring of trying an INSERT with DEFAULT instead of NULL (D'oh! Of course that won't work!). But, problem solved!